# Vagrant CentOs5.8 64bit with PHP5.2.x

Tags: linux, vagrant

Due project limitation it is necessary to run the project between PHP version < 5.3 and > 5.2.

We're deploying our environments through Vagrant, with CentOs 6.x. For this project we've created (downloaded) a CentOs 5.x box since this one does not ship automatically with PHP5.3.x

Yet hower the version that comes with CentOs5.x is 5.1.6 which is too low for the project. I've spend many hours searching through the internet for a suitable sollutions and tried many (atomic, downloading rpv, using CentOs testing repo) nothing really works nor is stable or easy to integrate with Vagrant and Puppet provisions.

The easiest sollution I've found which is do-able through Direct shell puppet provions

```
[c5-testing]
name=CentOS-5 Testing
baseurl=http://dev.centos.org/centos/$releasever/testing/$basearch/
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=http://dev.centos.org/centos/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-testing
includepkgs=php*
```

But running the `yum install php` will just yield me the PHP 5.1.6 version and not the expected PHP 5.2.x

I can see in the terminal that it is using this c5-testing repo.

Running `yum --enablerepo=c5-testing install php` even has less effects.

```
yum --enablerepo=c5-testing install php
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, priorities, security
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * addons: ftp.cvut.cz
 * base: ftp.cvut.cz
 * centosplus: ftp.cvut.cz
 * epel: mirror.karneval.cz
 * extras: ftp.cvut.cz
 * updates: ftp.cvut.cz
Reducing CentOS-5 Testing to included packages only
Finished
309 packages excluded due to repository priority protections
Setting up Install Process
Package php-5.1.6-39.el5_8.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```

Does anyone have more ideas regarding this topic, or has a CentOs box with a 5.2 version of PHP.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try this one http://shellboy.com/install-php-52-on-rhel-centos-6.html

Comment: [php-5.2 Repo](http://updates.interworx.com/iworx/RPMS/unsupported/php5/cos5x/x86_64/) Just add it in your yum repo and give it a shot

Comment: @Satish, yes, this iworx repo works much better than the atomicorp one. I ended up provisioning my machine with a reconfigured yum.conf `[iworx-unsupported]
name=IWorx Unsupported
baseurl=http://updates.interworx.com/iworx/RPMS/unsupported/php5/cos5x/$basearch/
gpgcheck=0`

Comment: So you are all good? If yes then let me put this in Answer section to you can answer it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was eventually able to mange it by manually specifying the etc/yum.conf repo (This could of course also move to /etc/yum.repo.d)

With the content:

```
[iworx-unsupported] 
name=IWorx Unsupported 
baseurl=http://updates.interworx.com/iworx/RPMS/unsupported/php5/cos5x/$basearch‌​/ 
gpgcheck=0
```

Please not that some values are hardcoded in the baseurl and might not 100% be compatible with a different installation.